# DataTable - how to sort by multiple columns?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using the jQuery DataTable. I am logging game events; there are several (player) turns in a (game) round:

```
    $('#events')
        .DataTable({
            data: [],
            paging: false,
            searching: false,
            info: false,
            columns: [
                {data: 'round', title: 'Round'},
                {data: 'turn', title: 'Round'},
                {data: 'event', title: 'Event'},
                {data: 'actor', title: 'Actor'}
            ]
        }).column(0).order('asc');
```

My question - how do I sort by round, then turn?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`columns.orderData`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.orderData) option to define multi-column ordering.

```
$('#events')
    .DataTable({
        data: [],
        paging: false,
        searching: false,
        info: false,
        columns: [
            {data: 'round', title: 'Round', orderData: [0, 1]},
            {data: 'turn', title: 'Round', orderData: [0, 1]},
            {data: 'event', title: 'Event'},
            {data: 'actor', title: 'Actor'}
        ]
    });
```